# Rails: make your own gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

With help of some tutorials, I made my first simple gem which adds Sass/CSS files to assets/stylesheets directory of the app.

It's awkward, but the problem is I don't know how to run my gem in the app.

gemspec:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'example/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "Example"
  spec.version       = Example::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["***"]
  spec.email         = ["***"]
  spec.description   = %q{Provide CSS styles}
  spec.summary       = %q{Provide CSS styles}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
  spec.add_development_dependency "redcarpet", "~> 1.17"
  spec.add_development_dependency "yard", "~> 0.7.5"
end
```

example.rb:

```
require "example/version"

module Example

    def self.install
        original_dir = Dir["/lib/example/*.css.scss"]
        original_dir.each do |f|
            name = File.basename('main', '.css.scss')
            destination_dir = "/app/assets/stylesheets/#{name}"
            FileUtils.cp(main, destination_folder)
        end
    end

end
```

Rakefile:

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require 'yard'
YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new
```

I believe that I should write some rake tasks, but I'm not pretty sure how can I do it.

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't know? add the link to the gem to the project's **Gemfile** that uses the gem, as follows: gem 'youe_gem_name', :path => '/path/to /your/gem/root'. then issue `bundle install` from the other projects folder. If it is an rails app, just run rails. And issue call to `Example.install` from within rails config.

Comment: Of course, I added it to Gemfile. But as you can see in `example.rb` my gem is adding `main.css.scss` to `app/assets/stylesheets`. I installed gem but don't know how to make it work

Comment: I see the two inconsistencies: You evaluate destination_dir, but then use destination_folder, then you enumerate f, but don't use it then.

Comment: And question: are you testing your gem inside if it, or outside from other gem/app?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's problem with example.rb. I just wanted to know, is it necessary to run gem by bundle install?

Comment: you can't run the gem with `bundle install`, becuase the command just installs the required gems, which you've specified in **gemspec/Gemfile**. To run a script with all dependencies you shell to use `bundle exec`. But how do you plan yo use your gem? in rails, or in an other gem?

Comment: I want to use it in rails apps

Comment: you need to specify/add this `gem 'example', :path => '/path/to/your/gem'` in rails **Gemfile**. then issue `bundle install` in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learnt how to solve my problem. The best way to run ruby code from gem file is to move it to rails generator. For example create file `lib/generators/initializer_generator.rb` which contains your code (I put an example):

```
class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  def create_initializer_file
    create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
  end
end
```

Then add your gem to Gemfile, install it and run `rails g initializer`